# How to Run Azure Function into running longer than 10 minutes

Tags: function, azure, consumption

How to Run Azure Function into running longer than 10 minutes?

My task is parsing csv file and storing data into database tables hardly it will take one hour time. But Azure function apps max timeout is 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your Function in an App Service plan instead of a Consumption plan, the default timeout is 30 minutes with no overall limit.

[Here's a link to the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout)

Answer (score 0):

Functions is not designed to run that long , check out this Data Lake example/tutorial to copy csv to sql DB

https://medium.com/@adilsonbna/using-azure-data-lake-to-copy-data-from-csv-file-to-a-sql-database-712c243db658

*You use the Copy Data tool to create a pipeline that copies data from CSV file data to a SQL database*.

Comment: Hi @Jarnstrom, First thanks for suggesting Azure Data Lake. And I have few doubts. 1)We have CSV files it is source every day we are created a new CSV file. Is it possible add dynamically CSV file into azure data lake.2)based on column value we need to process data is it also possible in data lake, let me know . Thanks in Advance